# Java and C: different outputs of same code

Tags: java, c

I have a piece of code ,when i compile it in **Java**   the output is different as compared to the output when it is compiled in **C**

```
class Hello{
    int m1() {
        System.out.println("m1 in Hello");
        return 10;
    }

    int m2() {
        System.out.println("m2 in Hello");
        return 20;
    }

    int m3() {
        System.out.println("m3 in Hello");
        return 30;
    }
}

public class Test36 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        System.out.println(h.m1() + "......" + h.m2() + "......." + h.m3());    
    }
}
```

**output**

in **Java**

> m1 in Hello
>   m2 in Hello
>   m3 in Hello
>   10……20…….30

while in C I am getting the following o/p.

> m3 in Hello
>   m2 in Hello
>   m1 in Hello
>   10 …..20 ……30

I was not expecting different outputs, Am I missing on some basic logic ?

Comment: This is not C code.  Please show how you're doing the string concatenation in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although that code would compile neither in C nor C++, your basic problem is here:

```
System.out.println(h.m1() + "......" + h.m2() + "......." + h.m3());
```

In C and C++ there are no constraints on how the compiler orders those calls. It could call m3 then m2 then m1, or m2 then m3 then m1, etc, etc... It is implementation defined behaviour and you cannot rely on it.

Comment: It's not implementation-defined - then the implementation would have to document how it does it - it is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have omitted the C code.

The reason for the different output is that in C the order of execution of functions in a single statement is implementation defined and can happen in any order. You cannot assume that functions called in a single expression will happen in any particular order, excepting where you have used one of a limited number of operators such as `&&` or `? :`.